# How export particular system from blender to OBJ file

Tags: opengl, graphics, export, blender

I created a graphic engine which is able to import meshes with their materials in an openGL context. Now my objective is to create a hair particular system on Blender and export it in OBJ + MTL files. I always did it but without material configuration (I just created a UV sphere adding hair on it using hair particular system and convert it to separate the hairs from the sphere). But when I configure a specific material for the particular system (for exemple in strand option the modification of the root size and the top size of the hair (50 to 1)) and next (after convertion) I export the particular system, the material is not considered. I would like the hairs look like triangles but it's not the case). In 'render' menu if I click on 'render image' the particular system appearence is good but if I click on 'render openGL' the material configuation is not considered like my exportation in OBJ file. Can you explain me why?

Do you have an idea how the exportation could considered the material configuration ?

Comment: "Particle system" perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your answer. I use particle systems (hair).